# machinectl not importing diskimage

Tags: 18.04, systemd, container

I was playing with systemd-nspawn. So I created a qcow2 disk image of 2 GB
 and Installed minimal Debian using debootstrap.

Then I tried to import it using machinectl but it fails every time giving error.

```
$ sudo machinectl import-raw Debian_Buster.qcow2
```

It interrupts with error.

```
Imported 86%.
Imported 87%.
Failed to decode and write: No space left on device
Exiting.
```

tried importing this after converting to raw. But same error, just that it fails at 27%.

using `df -h` command shows

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 udev            2.4G     0  2.4G   0% /dev
 tmpfs           497M  1.6M  496M   1% /run
 /dev/sda2        92G   11G   76G  13% /
 tmpfs           2.5G   34M  2.4G   2% /dev/shm
 tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
 tmpfs           2.5G     0  2.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 /dev/sda1       496M   49M  448M  10% /boot/efi
 /dev/sda3       145G  134G  9.5G  94% /home
 tmpfs           497M     0  497M   0% /run/user/119
 tmpfs           497M   24K  497M   1% /run/user/1000
 /dev/loop2      500M   17M  419M   4% /var/lib/machines
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

System Info:
System: Kubuntu 18.04.1
Systemd Ver. : systemd 237

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1510511 - Found the bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import Diskimage:

- Unmount `/var/lib/machines` & resize `/var/lib/machines.raw`:

  ```
  $ umount /var/lib/machines ; qemu-img resize -f raw /var/lib/machines.raw +16G
  ```
- Restart `machinectl` Service:

  ```
  $ systemctl restart /var/lib/machines
  ```
- Resize `btrfs` Volume:

  ```
  $ btrfs filesystem resize max /var/lib/machines
  ```